# Count Returns 1 instead of 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

I have a very basic Python function and the code seems to be OK but it returns a count of 1 instead of 3. All the function does is to look for even numbers in a list.

```
def even_count(integers):
count = 0
for number in integers:
    if number%2 == 0:
        count = count + 1
    return count

print(even_count([2,3,4,5,6,7]))
```

I have initialized the count variable at 0 and the for loop seems to be OK so I don't understand what else is wrong.

Comment: Can you confirm that your indentation is correct? Doesn't appear so

Comment: `return count` appears to be *inside* the loop...

Comment: that is the indentation that i have created. is that what the problem is?

Comment: @RaulGonzales: It's definitely not your exact indentation; you'd get a `SyntaxError` if the `def` was indented identically to the following line. If all the lines but the first should be indented exactly one additional level, but you don't know how to fix it yourself, tell us.

Comment: I appreciate everyone's efforts but you can clearly tell that i am a total newbie when it comes to Python so why the down votes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your indentation is incorrect. Your `return` statement is triggered on the first iteration of your for loop, therefore you exit your function after only a single iteration.

Your solution is to use proper indentation:

```
def even_count(integers):
    count = 0
    for number in integers:
        if number%2 == 0:
            count = count + 1
    return count

print(even_count([2,3,4,5,6,7]))
```

Yields:

```
3
```

Further explanation:

When you define a function use `def my_function(*args)`, you need to indent all lines following that function definition that you intend to be contained in the function. In this case, you are returning a value from your function, and that value `count` should only be returned once you have iterated through all numbers in your passed list `integers` and evaluated by your logic (your `if` statement).

A more simplistic solution:

```
integers = [2,3,4,5,6,7]

count = sum(1 for i in integers if i%2==0)
```

Yields:

```
3
```

Answer (score 0):

Indentation matters a lot. Your current code returning result as 1

```
def even_count(integers):
    count = 0
    for number in integers:
        if number%2 == 0:
            count = count + 1
        return count # inside for loop

print(even_count([2,3,4,5,6,7]))
```

With correct indentation

```
def even_count(integers):
    count = 0
    for number in integers:
        if number%2 == 0:
            count = count + 1
    return count # outside for loop

print(even_count([2,3,4,5,6,7])) #returns 3
```

If need one liner

```
sum([1 for i in [2,3,4,5,6,7] if i%2==0])
```

Answer (score 0):

You indentation is indeed not quite right.
Consider avoiding the loop entirely, because less code means less bugs.
One option is to use [functools.reduce](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce):

```
import functools

def even_count(integers):
  f = lambda acc, elem: acc + (0 if elem%2 else 1)
  return functools.reduce(f, integers, 0)

print(even_count([2,3,4,5,6,7]))
```

You can obviously inline the lambda expression, too, but I wrote it out this way for clarity.